# Add a div element depending on condition in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, conditional

Hello,

I develop a LWC and I have 2 displays because a condition.

They are very similar but a "div" element is inside the second display but it is on the top of the LWC.

This is my first display (it is only an example):

```
<lightning-layout-item>
<template for:each={data} for:item='aData'>
   {aData.label}     
</template>
```

My second display is something like this (it is only an example):

```
<lightning-layout-item>
<template if:false={isFullVersion}>
    <div>
</template>
<template for:each={data} for:item='aData'>
   {aData.label}     
</template>
<template if:false={isFullVersion}>
    </div>
</template>
```

The difference is the adding of the "div" element between the "" and the "" elements but the second display doesn't work (I can't deploy my LWC) because I can't only add a "div" (the opening "" only) element into a "template" element, I should add the opening and the closing (" and "").

My problem is I don't want to have 2 big conditions in my LWC like this (because it is not beautifull and it duplicates the code):

```
<lightning-layout-item>

<template if:true={isFullVersion}>
    <template for:each={data} for:item='aData'>
       {aData.label}
    </template>
</template>

<template if:false={isFullVersion}>
    <div>
        <template for:each={data} for:item='aData'>
           {aData.label}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Do you know if there is a way to do it properly (not duplicate my code)?

Thanks

Comment: so you want to wrap `{aData.label}` in div if `isFullVersion` is false other wise not right?

Comment: I would like to wrap the foreach in a div element only when isFullVersion is false

Comment: so what is the purpose of having div? just for display?

Comment: Yes, the div is for the display because it uses css

Comment: then you can apply the CSS dynamically using the class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to change the styles based on the `isFullVersion` attribute value. So you need to add the CSS dynamically using the class attribute.

**.css**

```
.fullVersionStyle{
    display:block;
    // add more css 
}

.regularVersionStyle{
    display: inline;
    // add more CSS 
}
```

Write getter for a class attribute in JS controller.

**.js**

```
get divVersionClasses(){
    return this.isFullVersion ? 'fullVersionStyle' : 'regularVersionStyle';
}
```

Use the class in the HTML file.

**.html**

```
<template if:false={isFullVersion}>
    <div class={divVersionClasses}>
        <template for:each={data} for:item='aData'>
           {aData.label}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It is what I wanted, thank you.